# Codeigniter pass variable between functions

Tags: codeigniter

How can i pass variable from function a to b in codeigniter controller.

```
function a()
{

   $id = $this->input->post('id');

}
```

I want $id from function a to be passing to b

```
function b() 
{

    if($id) 
    {
       .....

    }

}
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used `$this->session->set_userdata('a', $a); to pass the variable and it can be accessed by all method within the controller. to access it i used $b = $this->session->userdata('a');`

thanks for all the help :D

Answer (score 2):

create $id

```
public $id = false;
```

then use

```
function a(){
    $this->id = $this->input->post('id');
}

function b(){
    if($this->id){.....}
}
```

in controls class

```
class TestApi extends MY_Controller {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public t1 = false;

        public function a () {
            $this->t1 = true;
        }

        public function b () {
            a();
            if($this->t1){
                ...
            }
        }
}
```

---

or try global var? but not a good idea in framework

```
$a1 = 5;
function Test()
{
    $GLOBALS['a1'] = 1;
}

Test();
echo $a1;
```

---

In the Same Class? maybe should check var or what u get from input?

```
Class Test{
    public $t = 1;

    public function a(){
        $this->t = 20;
    }

    public function b(){
        echo $this->t;
    }

}

$TestClass = new Test;

echo $TestClass->t;
echo "-";
echo $TestClass->a();
echo ">";
echo $TestClass->t;
```

Comment: Thanks for respon, the code works but why i dont get value in variable id?, it keep returning null value..

Comment: function a, b in the same class ?

Comment: when i use var_dump on post, it give the value from input text, when i tried to pass it as you suggested it return null

Comment: can you print $this->id and $this->input->post('id') in function a?

Comment: do i have to print it in view? if yes, how to print it? sory i'm still learning by tiral and error for this. bdw thanks for respond

Comment: 1. print then exit. 2. put in other var, print in view. 3. file_put_contents,

Comment: Thanks for respond, i used session to pass the variable and its work, thanks for all the respond :D

Answer (score 0):

```
function a(){
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $this->b($id);

}

function b($id){
    if ($id) {
        //....
    } else {
        //.....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for respon, i tried that but it give me this error Severity: Warning

Message: Missing argument 1, it probably because i call function b from iframe in view, maybe this error happend because when i call this function from view i dont provide parameter id to be passed...